# Using two columns of a dataframe as one axis in Pandas.plot or matplotlib.plot

Tags: datetime, matplotlib, pandas

I am new to python and data analysis. I have a dataframe consisting of 3 columns - site (string object) , date (datetime) and value (integer). I want to plot a graph using the x axis as a concatenation of site and date and y axis as value. However I am not able to merge these 2 columns properly. It gives an error saying expecting a string or buffer but datetime.date found.

`df['index'] =  df['site'] + df['date']`

This is the line that I use. df is my dataframe.

Any ideas would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Give us a tiny dataset to make it easy to test solutions (like, six rows, with three x-axis-values

(2) For your creating-an-index-column approach, just convert the datetime object to a string, e.g.:

```
df['index'] =  ' '.join([df['site'], str(df['date'])])
```

(3) What kind of plot do you need? A bar plot, with that kind of categorical x-axis? Will there be only one value per grouped x-location?

Comment: Thank you. This worked as required. I needed a bar plot.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Could you accept the answer? It will help people looking for questions to answer, or answered questions. (Also I get more points in the game of stackoverflow.)